# Grub2 (Efi) boot via PXE - load config file automatically

Tags: grub2, grub-efi, pxe

I´ve got a problem booting my OS via Grub2 bootloader.

Environment:

I´ve got a PXE-Boot Infrastructure and want to test PXE-Booting Grub2.efi via Network (TFTP).

Downloading the efi-file to the client works and grub gets loaded on the machine - I can see the grub prompt `grub>` - I´m using Grub Version 2.00.

I´ve created a config file (`grub.cfg`) and placed it in the same TFTP-Directory as the `grub.efi` file.

I can see from the TFTP-logs that GRUB gets downloaded - and obviously loaded on the client - and afterwards the `grub.cfg` get downloaded by grub.

My `grub.cfg` looks as follows:

```
set root=(hd0,gpt1)
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
boot
```

Minimalistically I just want to boot Windows with GRUB. Please don´t ask why; that would take too long to describe…

I would expect GRUB to find the downloaded `grub.cfg` file and load Windows.

What happens: I just get thrown to the `grub>` prompt.

When I load the `grub.cfg` from the grub prompt via

```
configfile /grub.cfg
```

the OS gets loaded perfectly, so that seems to be OK so far.

So my problem is, how can I get GRUB to automatically load the config file and boot Windows?

Answer (score 1):

**Grub looks for a config file `/grub/grub.cfg`** or `/grub/x86_64-efi/grub.cfg` (or similar).

**NB**: It is a path from the TFTP server root. That means even if you run your Grub binary from a path like `$tftproot/path/to/grubnetx64.efi`, don't try to put the direcotry `grub/` to the same directory, but really to your TFTP root: `$tftproot/grub/`

### How to find out

In the Grub console:

```
grub> cat (memdisk)/grub.cfg
if [ -e $prefix/x86_64-efi/grub.cfg ]; then
    source Sprefix/x86_64-efi/grub.cfg
else
    source Sprefix/grub.cfg
fi
```

And the important part, what the `$prefix` is:

```
grub> echo $prefix
(tftp,x.x.x.x)/grub
```

Comment: My $prefix is undefined.  Where does grub get the tftp server ip from?

Comment: I guess from DHCP server. That's where you get it when booting over PXE.

Comment: I found my issue.  I'm using a DHCP Proxy so I had to place the PXE server option 66 in the existing DHCP server.  There is a bug in Grub.

Answer (score 1):

Check your DHCP server is setting the `next-server` option. For example with ISC DHCPd:

```
next-server 192.168.0.254;
```

grub uses this to know where to look for a config file as described here: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Network.html

If the client is downloading `grub.efi`, but not `grub.cfg`, the client boots to the `grub>` prompt and `$net_default_server` is empty, missing or incorrect next-server is likely the cause.

```
grub> echo $net_default_server
```

In my experience, `$prefix` will always be a `(memdisk)` path, whether or not `next-server` is set correctly and grub downloads a configuration file from the TFTP server:

```
grub> echo $prefix
(memdisk)/boot/grub
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it in a  `menuentry` and `set default="0"`.

Reference: [wiki.ubuntu.com - UEFI/PXE-netboot-install](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/PXE-netboot-install)